# Click button on a website using javascript from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript

I wanted to click on the Wiki button of the below given url

https://courses.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS100.1x/1T2015/wiki/BerkeleyX.CS100.1x.1T2015/

How can I click on the same button after every 5 minutes to get the latest result.

I wanted to do this in google chrome how can I do this using javascript or by using any chrome extension and code in the same?

Awaiting for your response!!

Comment: where is _Wiki button_ in URL

Comment: Use this url https://www.edx.org/ and click on courses it would also work for me

Comment: You want to recreate a "click" behaviour is that right ?

Comment: you need to be loggon on to see that page ... I guess only few people will sign up there in order to help you ;-) What do you want to do with the data retrieved ? Simply display it in the browser ? Or export it somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do [web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

In javascript, you could try [artoo](https://medialab.github.io/artoo/).

> artoo.js is a piece of JavaScript code meant to be run in your browser's console to provide you with some scraping utilities.

Comment: I don't want to scrap data I just want it should be auto clicked on the given button rest would do manually

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and in `setInterval` you can trigger the click.

```js
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);
```

Comment: How Can I use to to click a button on the webpage?

Comment: I think only when you are able to modify the source code

Comment: I am not getting you.. Is it doable?

Comment: you need to write you code between `setInterval` function to execute it in loop